# Conversation not happening in Amazon Echo

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

**Hi My intent schema is like this:**

```
{
  "intents": [
    {
      "slots": [
        {
          "name": "Literalslot",
          "type": "AMAZON.LITERAL"
        }
      ],
      "intent": "ConverseGenieIntent"
    },
    {
      "intent": "AMAZON.HelpIntent"
    },
    {
      "intent": "AMAZON.StopIntent"
    },
    {
      "intent": "AMAZON.CancelIntent"
    }
  ]
}
```

**And my utterances are:**

```
ConverseGenieIntent {hello|Literalslot}
ConverseGenieIntent {validate payroll|Literalslot}
ConverseGenieIntent {no no|Literalslot}
ConverseGenieIntent {no|Literalslot}
ConverseGenieIntent {no its not correct|Literalslot}
ConverseGenieIntent {no my payroll id is |Literalslot}
ConverseGenieIntent {its not correct|Literalslot}
ConverseGenieIntent {its wrong|Literalslot}
ConverseGenieIntent {no|Literalslot}
ConverseGenieIntent {that's not correct|Literalslot}
ConverseGenieIntent {that is not correct|Literalslot}
ConverseGenieIntent {hi yeah|Literalslot}
ConverseGenieIntent {what is your name|Literalslot}
ConverseGenieIntent {may i know your name please|Literalslot}
ConverseGenieIntent {hey what is your name|Literalslot}
```

My skill is actually a bot which gives multiple conversations.

**Expected converstion:**

User: Alexa ask genie to say hello.

Alexa: Welcome to genie.

User: Start session..

Alexa: Please tell me the store number?

User: one two three four

Alexa: Are you calling from BRAYBOOK 1234?

User: Yes

Alexa: Please tell me payroll ID?

User: 5678
(....and continues for at least three more conversations)

**But while testing in Echo:**

User: Alexa ask genie to say hello.

Alexa: Welcome to genie. Please tell me the store number?

User: one two three four

Alexa: Sorry i couldn't find that

.....ALWAYS THE CONVERSATION STOPS HERE.......     I really don't know why...   I don't wanna use dialog directives as the response from the lambda function comes from a DialogFlow bot.
I tested the skill in service simulator the skill is working fine!!!   This problem happens only why i test my skill in Echo.

Answer (score 0):

AMAZON.LITERAL takes one [literal](/questions/tagged/literal) at a time. You can only say one or two or three ... at a time. Plus, if you want a group of literal to do further processing, then you have to use State Management to receive the input one by one.

**Proposed Conversation** 
Alexa: Please tell me the store number?

User: one

Alexa: Next Number?

User: two

Alexa: Next Number?

User: three

Comment: Thanks that was really helpful. Can you also tell me where the sample code for State Management in python is available?

Comment: Official Link for SM is in node.js : https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs#making-skill-state-management-simpler

Comment: You can take an idea from this, https://github.com/nmyster/python-alexa

Answer (score 0):

Hey it not actually like that. Your answer is wrong. I don't have to give input as "One" then "two" and after it asks "three" ....No not like that.  Inputs like "1234" can be given as it worked well in Echo device. Never test your skill in Echosim.io. Always test in an Amazon device.

Comment: what slot type you have used then?

Comment: AMAZON.LITERAL is the slot type i used.